# KeyboardInterrupt doesn't work when arcgisscripting module is loaded

Tags: python, arcpy

The `KeyboardInterrupt` exception -- thrown when Ctrl-C, or Ctrl-Break on some machines, are pressed in a Python console window -- is commonly used to gracefully break out of long-process loops, allowing your script to perform cleanup, logging etc, before exiting.

Under my ArcGIS 9.3.1 SP2/Windows XP SP3 environment, there is an issue with catching the KeyboardInterrupt exception if the `arcgisscripting` module is loaded. Instead of hitting the KeyboardInterrupt catch statement, the script aborts abruptly, spitting out the following message:

`forrtl: error (200): program aborting due to control-C event`

If the arcgisscripting module is not loaded (removed from the `import` statement), the KeyboardInterrupt exception is thrown and processed properly.

From what I've read this is due to the use of Fortran in the arcgisscripting module which somehow overrides Python's interrupt processing.

Here's an example script you can use to test and reproduce the issue. Save it as a Python script, run it from the Windows command prompt and press Ctrl-C (Ctrl-Break on some machines) to test whether the KeyboardInterrupt exception is processed. Simply toggle the commenting for the `import arcgisscripting` line.

```
#import arcgisscripting
import time

try:
    while(True):
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "KeyboardInterrupt detected!"
```

Anyone know of a workaround to this problem? Thanks in advance for any insights you may have.

edit: here is my test script using Jason's suggestion which unfortunately doesn't work:

```
import arcgisscripting
import signal
import time

def ctrlc(sig, frame):
    raise KeyboardInterrupt("CTRL-C!")

print "Waiting 65s ..."
time.sleep(65)
print "Installing SIGINT handler"
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, ctrlc)

try:
    while(True):
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "KeyboardInterrupt detected!"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a Windows-only workaround for this. It uses the `msvcrt` module, which is a Windows-only wrapper for the Visual C++ runtime, to read which keyboard character code was last received. It doesn't override the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, so I specified it should look for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd>. When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> in my test script it will raise the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception. If you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> it will still abruptly kill the script, however.

There are likely other ways to do this on *nix but I only needed this for Windows.

```
import arcgisscripting
import msvcrt
import time

def kbfunc():
   x = msvcrt.kbhit()
   if x:
      ret = ord(msvcrt.getch())
   else:
      ret = 0
   return ret

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        while(True):
            time.sleep(1)

            # Check to see if Ctrl-Alt-Q is pressed
            x = kbfunc()
            if x == 16: # Ctrl-Alt-Q
                raise KeyboardInterrupt

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "KeyboardInterrupt detected!"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try reinstalling a custom handler for SIGINT using the [`signal` module](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.4/lib/module-signal.html) after importing arcgisscripting.

```
import arcgisscripting
import signal

def ctrlc(sig, frame):
    raise KeyboardInterrupt("CTRL-C!")

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, ctrlc)
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It unfortunately doesn't seem to work, the forrtl error still occurs instead of my KeyboardInterrupt exception. Also, the help file on the signal module says that SIGINT is already translated to KeyboardInterrupt by default. So unfortunately it looks like arcgisscripting is still overriding it.

Comment: You might want to check the timing of when you reset the signal handler -- try doing it after doing your `arcgisscripting.create()` call, as many more DLLs get loaded after than, one of which must be the offending library that changes the signal handler.

Comment: In my test script I am not even calling `arcgisscripting.create()`, just importing the module. I also tried sticking a `time.sleep()` of 65 seconds in between the import statement and resetting the signal handler, just in case it was some timing issue but that did not help.